# why two thread produce below result ( ocjp test)?

Tags: java

I have below ocjp test which i don't understand the answer (as I thought the answer should be A+D,but the correct answer is A+B), anyone can explain that?:

> Given a piece of code. Which two are possible results? (Select two)
>
> ```
> public class Cruiser {
>     private int a = 0;
>
>     public void foo() {
>         Runnable r = new LittleCruiser();
>         new Thread(r).start();
>         new Thread(r).start();
>     }
>
>     public static void main(String arg[]) {
>         Cruiser c = new Cruiser();
>         c.foo();
>     }
>
>     public class LittleCruiser implements Runnable {
>         public void run() {
>             int current = 0;
>             for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
>                 current = a;
>                 System.out.print(current + ", ");
>                 a = current + 2;
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> A) 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 4, 6, 6,
> B) 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 
>  C) 0, 2,
>   4, 6, 8, 10, 2, 4, 
>  D) 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 12, 12,
>   14, 14, 
>  E) 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14,

Answers: A, B

Comment: I don't like multiple-choice homework.  Do you have any essay-type questions?

Comment: How could D be correct? Each thread only prints four numbers, and there are only two threads.

Comment: @khelwood yes you are right.  But what if the answer is : 0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 6, 6

Comment: @tainy That isn't one of the options.

Comment: @MartinJames even if it's multiple-choice homework, it's still important to understand how things work. It's not as if the OP were asking for the answers. He knows them, but doesn't understand them. Multithreading is not that simple to grasp and debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `run` method has a `for` loop that executes 4 times and prints something each time. As you run 2 threads, you should end up printing 8 things, so answers D and E are not possible.

As for what is being displayed, you need to see that `a` is shared and remember that the threads run in parallel: it's possible that `run` from thread 1 runs entirely and then the `run` of thread 2 runs entirely, or they get mixed up. In the latter case, thread 1 may be inside the `for` loop printing something, and then instead of executing the `+2` you switch to thread 2 and print again the same number.

Answer A is possible: thread 1 starts and executes `current = a;` in the `for` loop, so `current` is equal to `0` and `a` hasn't been modified. Then thread 2 starts and executes the `for` 3 times, thus printing `0, 2, 4,`. Let's say it also sets `a` to `6`. Then we're back to thread 1 that continues with its `current` being equal to `0`, and it has time to print 3 times, thus printing `0, 2, 4,`. It also sets `a` to `6`. Then we're back on thread 2 that gets `a` and prints it ie '6,', then we're back on thread `that also gets`a` and prints it ie '6,'.

Answer B is possible: for ex thread 1 runs entirely then thread 2. Or the threads get mixed up but not too much, eg each thread has time to execute the 3 lines inside the `for` loop before the context switches to the other thread.

Answer C is not possible: you can only go back to a previous number if you do a `current = a`. As you go back to `2`, it means that thread 1 already printed `0`, then did the `+2`, then `current = a`. Then thread 2 runs entirely and prints `2, 4, 6, 8`. Then thread 1 goes back to printing `2`. It's not possible to be able to print `10` then go back to `2` (you could go back to `4` though).

Answer (score 1):

it's because private int a = 0; it's shared across the two threads. So both threads are interacting with this variable at the same time.
The following is likely to happen:

0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14

0, 0, 2, 4, 2, 6, 4, 6,

0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 2, 4, 6,